# What does \x6d\xe3\x85 mean?

Tags: c, openssl, byte

I don't know what is that, I found this in the openSSL source code.

Is those some sort of byte sequence? Basically I just need to convert my `char *` to that kind of style as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly a byte sequence.

Comment: Did someone steal the rest of your question? It ends with a comma, and never seems to get around to explaining what the rest of your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you read was

```
char foo[] = "\x6d\xe3\x85";
```

then that is the same as

```
char foo[] = { 0x6d, 0xE3, 0x85, 0x00 };
```

Further, I can tell you that `0x6D` is the ASCII code point for `'m'`, `0xE3` is the ISO 8859.1 code point for `'ã'`, and `0x85` is the Windows-1252 code point for `'…'`.

But without knowing more about the context, I can't tell you how to "convert [your] char * to that kind of style as a parameter", except to say that you might not need to do any conversion at all!  The `\x` notation allows you to write string constants containing arbitrary byte sequences into *your source code*.  If you already have an arbitrary byte sequence in a buffer in your program, I can't imagine your needing to back-convert it to `\x` notation before feeding it to OpenSSL.

Comment: What do the code points have to do with this? Also, why are you citing two different encodings? A string can only have exactly one. But I'm pretty sure the string is not meant to be represented by a human readable string encoding.

Comment: Each of the encodings I cited is a superset of the previous; this *could* be a representation in Windows-1252 of the string `"mã…"`.  I agree it's probably not meant to be text at all, but any time you see a hex string with 0x[4567]N bytes in it, text is a possibility to be considered.

Comment: is there a sheet that I can see ?  example: 0x6D -> m . as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It's a byte sequence in hexadecimal. `\x6d\xe3\x85` is hex character `6d` followed by hex `e3`, followed by hex `85`. The syntax is `\xnn` where *nn* is your hex sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The `\x` sequence is used to escape byte values in hexadecimal notation. So the sequence you've cited escapes the bytes `6D`, `E3` and `85` which translate into 109, 227 and 133. While `6D` can also be represented as the character `m` in ASCII, you cannot represent the later two in ASCII as it only covers the range 0..127. So for values beyond 127 you need a special way to write them, and the `\x` is such a way.

The other way is to escape as octal numbers using `\<number>`, for example 109 would be `\155`.

If you need explicit byte values it's better to use these escape sequences since (AFAIK) the C standard doesn't guarantee that your string will be encoded using ASCII. So when you compile for example on an EBCDIC system your `m` would be represented as byte value 148 instead of 109.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet to understand more about hex byte sequence..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char word[]="\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f"; 
    printf("%s\n", word);

    return 0;
}

/*
Output:
$
$ ./a.out
Hello
$
*/
```

Comment: @all An upvote for the code example would have been encouraging! :)